# Dynamically align html list in wordwrap curve?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-shapes

I'm trying wrap an HTML list into a curve. I'd like to avoid specifying each list element position so that when items are added it's location is automatically calculated.

I'm attaching an image of what I'm trying to accomplish.
Thanks!

[image: List]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`shape-outside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside) in combination with `float` and a negative `margin`.

Create a circular element with `border-radius: 50%`, let it `float: left` and set `shape-outside: circle()`. This way, the text will be floatet outside on the circular shape. Now you can set a negative right margin, i.e. `margin-right: -6em;` to pull the floated text inside the circular element.

Here is a working example:

```css
.curve {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: purple;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -6em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  shape-outside: circle();
}

ul {
  padding: 2.5em 0;
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="curve"></div>
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
```